# Mind mapping software that supports shared nodes

Tags: mind-mapping

I've been using XMind to do simple mind maps on my iPad. I want to create something where some of the leaf nodes are shared/linked from multiple branches. I guess this will end up being a bit untidy and bit more like a network map.

Update: I'm trying to prepare OKRs ([Objectives and Key results](https://www.wikihow.com/Write-Objectives-and-Key-Results-(OKRs))) so maybe there's a visual tool for specifically this